# Трёхсполовиноймиллионый

Tags: орфография

Надо писать *трёхсполовиноймиллионый* или по-другому?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Орфографический словарь-справочник](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/475727/%D0%A2%D1%80%D1%91%D1%85%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9)**

Надо писать: ***трех с половиной миллионный*** (31/2-миллионный)

Подобная запись встречается редко (она заменяется цифровой), но читается  слово именно таким образом.

Слитно или раздельно? Орфографический словарь-справочник. — М.: Русский язык. Б. З. Букчина, Л. П. Какалуцкая. 1998.